# Scanned pictures, removing huge black areas (win32)

Tags: images

I have received a directory of scanned pages (png). Before printing them I would like to remove the huge black areas as they would waste tint. Is there a way to accomplish this using some batch processing tool?

I have heard that XnView might be able to do such thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with XnView, but Gimp has a fairly robust batch processing capability

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/